# Varaince decomposition without stochastic variance

Tags: variance, variance-decomposition

I am working on an analysis that doesn’t feel natural until now. I am trying to analyze a dataset that consists of the prediction results of forest growth simulators, so actually I’m trying to make a model of model results. Or better I try to decompose the variance of simulation results. 
The Forest growth simulators (two totally different ones) were used to predict stembiomass/tree over a certain period in different situations of the starting state of the forest and under climate change conditions. For each combination of forest model/climate model/plot  , ten possible parameter sets were used (chosen after calibration independently within each plot for each forest model separately).

What I want 
I would like to quantify  the variance in the output explained by each of the sources.
Difficulties for an unambiguous variance decomposition are
-   The deterministic character of the residual error of whatever model we would make. (Although we could see this prognosis as a source of random variation within the combinations of FM/CM/plot, it is still a deterministic source of variation.) 
-       Overfitting wil be a probable result and I would like to find a general method 
-   The big and not per se linear interaction between the ‘sources of variation’.
-   The nesting of prognosis in the combination of plot and forest model
I am interested in a method that can handle the decomposition of variance in such a situation, where no real stochastic variance is present and the result is a function of the sources we are willing to study.

I’m new on the statistical forum so if my question is not posed as supposed please tell me what is not clear so I can get somewhere at the end :)

Thank you very much in advance for your eventual suggestions
Joanna